# Develop a Service Fabric Web Application without redeploying after each file change

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have stateless .net core 2 Fabric Service Web Application creating using one of the templates that comes with Service Fabric SDK. It is a real pain to develop since I have to do a full deploy before I can see any changes to code/html/script. In my case that operation takes more than 5 minutes.

I have looked at this article that states how it can be done by running the web app from the commandline.

That article is based on Net Core RC2. Does anyone has an updated example on how to do this?

https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-with-kestrel-and-service-fabric

Comment: I have opened a support case with Azure developer support to find a solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

Together with Azure Developer Support i found a solution to speed up the development process

I Fabric Explorer you need to find the node where you Web Application is running. I my case that is _Node_0

By SF SDK design, local SF published file is under C:\SfDevCluster\Data_App\ this folder. In my environment, the website file path is C:\SfDevCluster\Data_App_Node_0\Application1Type_App1\Web1Pkg.Code.1.0.0\wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist

So you can also find your HTML, CSS, JS and other static resources under below path:
C:\SfDevCluster\Data_App[node_id][application_type_and_instance_name][service_type_and_version]\

You can just modify the files in this folder, then the change will immediately apply to your local test web browser. Please notice if your service is hosted by micro-service running in several nodes, you may need to modify all nodes files because load balancer may access any folder files randomly.

Comment: After working with this solution for a few days ... it is not really optimal. It works and is defiantly faster than redeploying all the time. I have created a stand alone (non fabric cluster) web application and is writing my code there. Then once in a while i copy the files to the location where fabric service is storing the files. There must be a better way